# Unable to save content in text file using java

Tags: java, file, itext

I read the pdf file using iText Pdf reader. After that i am tying to save content in a text file. I am using following code. But here content is not writing to file. Here, I read the whole pdf page by page but if read only one page then it is writing to file. why this code not able to save whole content in the specified text file. However this code print all the content in the console. can anyone help please where I am wrong?

```
public class PdfReadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PdfReader reader;
        String textFromPage;
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        FileWriter fw=null;

        try {
            reader = new PdfReader("pdf location");
            int nPages=reader.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println(nPages);
            for(int i = 1; i <=n Pages; i++){
                textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
                System.out.println("page" + i + " " + textFromPage);
                fw = new FileWriter("input.txt", true);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(textFromPage);

                System.out.println(textFromPage);
            }

            reader.close();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a new `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` inside the loop. Create only one at the beginning of the loop and use it inside the loop, so instead of

```
for(int i=1;i<=nPages;i++){
    textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
    System.out.println("page"+i+" "+textFromPage);
    fw=new FileWriter("input.txt",true);
    bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(textFromPage);
    System.out.println(textFromPage);
}
```

do

```
fw=new FileWriter("input.txt",true);
bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
for(int i=1;i<=nPages;i++){
    textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
    System.out.println("page"+i+" "+textFromPage);
    bw.write(textFromPage);
}
```

Another side note: Using FileWriter creates a writer that uses the system encoding to write text to a file. That might not be the charset you want to use. It's better to use `new OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream, String)` and specify the charset to be used explicitly.

Comment: Just a small addition - if you do for some reason need to create the `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` inside the loop (I'm not sure why you'd need to, but it's not impossible), you should also close them (`bw.close()` and `fw.close()`) inside the loop. That will be less efficient than @Lothar's suggestion, because it's opening and closing the files repeatedly, but it's a possible option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However I have used OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream, String) and it is woking fine.

Comment: @MohammadHasan So if the answer helped and things are working now as expected, you might accept the answer so it will disappear from the "open question list" ;-)